# Length restrictions on USB 3 cables with USB 2 powered devices

Tags: power, usb, cables

I have this very specific situation where I want to get an understanding of the cable lengths in a USB cable setup.

I have 3 USB 2.0 devices that require bus power. So I've connected these 3 with a USB 3.0 powered hub to my computer. My question is about the maximum length all the cables can have.

Is there a maximum length from each device to the USB hub and from the USB hub to my computer? I've read it's supposed to be 3 meters, but does that include the entire length (device -> hub -> Computer) ? Or is it from Device to Hub and another 3 from Hub to computer?

Answer (score 1):

The length of any given cable is limited. The chart below should help to show what is recommended.

[image]

Your use of a powered hub is a good idea. For applications where five hubs are strung together to gain use of up to 6 cable lengths (counting the final device cable which may be captured with the device such as a mouse or keyboard) you would want to make sure that any of those hubs connected directly to load devices were powered units. The reason for this is that I have measured voltage drops in a typical 2 meter USB 2.0 cable such that only about 4.4 -> 4.7V is delivered to the device when the maximum 500 mA is consumed at the device end. If this type of load was strung through even two sets of cables the Bus voltage gets too low to even be functional.